# Odd perfect squares whose decimal representation consist only of 1's and o's

Tags: number-theory, open-problem

Are there any odd perfect squares (apart from the trivial 1), whose decimal representations only uses 1 and 0?

Working modulo 8, we can get that the last 3 digits must be 001. However, since $4251^2 = 18071001 $, there goes my hope of showing that the last $n$ numbers be be of the form $0 0 \ldots 0 0 1$.

---

This question is motivated by the standard questions of asking if the repunit can be a perfect square, or if $10^n+1$ can be a perfect square.

Comment: I used a quick-and-dirty Mathematica routine to try all numbers of this form up to $\approx 10^{17}$ (as $11000011010100000_2 = 100000_{10}$) and it only found the trivial solution. That’s not to say that one doesn’t exist, but it’s big if it does.

Comment: Related in the WolframAlpha article: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SquareNumber.html : "It is conjectured that, other than $10^{2n}$, $4\times 10^{2n}$ and $9 \times 10^{2n}$, there are only a finite number of squares having exactly two distinct nonzero digits (Guy 1994, p. 262)."

Comment: Also related (actually the same question): http://mathoverflow.net/questions/22/can-n2-have-only-digits-0-and-1-other-than-n-10k

Comment: @LordSoth Thanks! Should this be closed as a duplicate then?

Comment: @CalvinLin Why should it? They too couldn't figure it out anyway :)

Comment: Not only that, but the two sites are separate. It's not a duplicate of a question here, is it? :-)

Comment: By the rule of nines, the digital root of the square can only be 0, 1, 4 or 7, so $10^n + 1$ can not be a perfect square.

Comment: @CiaPan Thanks. Note that it's "consist only of 1's and 0's". Your argument doesn't rule out numbers of the form $ 10^a + 10^b + 10^c + 1 $.

Comment: Of course. My note applies only to the last part of your comment starting with 'This question is motivated by...' :)

Answer (score 1):

Just some working:

if $x=d_m d_{m-1} d_{m-2}\dots d_1 d_0, \space d_0 = 1, d_i=0 \text{ or } 1$ is the number we're looking for,

denote $x_n=d_m d_{m-1} d_{m-2}\dots d_{n+1} d_n$

So,
$$ x =x_0 = 10x_1+d_0 = 10x_1+1 =y^2 $$ for some $y$
$$ 10x_1+1=y^2 $$
$$ 10x_1=y^2-1 $$
$$ 10x_1=(y+1)(y-1) $$
$$ 2.5.x_1=(y+1)(y-1) $$

so
$$ y+1=2k \text{ or } 5k $$
or
$$ y-1=2k \text{ or } 5k $$

$$ y=2k-1 \text{ or } 5k-1 \text{ or } 2k+1 \text{ or } 5k+1 $$

**I.e $ y = 1 \mod 2, \text{ or } \space 1 \text{ or } 4 \mod 5 $.**

Also
$ x_1=10x_2 + d_1 $ so $ x_1=10x_2 \text{ or } x_1=10x_2 + 1 $

I.e.
$$ 10(10x_2[+1])+1=y^2 $$
$$ 100.x_2=y^2-[1,11] $$
So
$$ 10^2.x_2=[2k-1 \text{ or } 5k-1 \text{ or } 2k+1 \text{ or } 5k+1]^2-[1,11] $$
$$ =2^2k^2-2k-[0,10] $$ or
$$ =2^2k^2+2k-[0,10] $$ or
$$ =5^2k^2-10k-[0,10] $$ or
$$ =5^2k^2+10k-[0,10] $$

Similarly
$ x_2 = 10x_3+d_2 = 10x_3 \text{ or } 10x_3 + 1 $

$$ 10^3.x_3 $$
$$ =2^2k^2-2k-[0,10,20] $$ or
$$ =2^2k^2+2k-[0,10,20] $$ or
$$ =5^2k^2-10k-[0,10,20] $$ or
$$ =5^2k^2+10k-[0,10,20] $$

Generalising
$$ 10^n.x_n $$
$$ =2^2k^2-2k-10l $$ or
$$ =2^2k^2+2k-10l $$ or
$$ =5^2k^2-10k-10l $$ or
$$ =5^2k^2+10k-10l, 0<=l<n $$

So firstly, $ \mod 10 $
$$ 2^2k^2-2k = 0 $$ or
$$ 2^2k^2+2k = 0 $$ or
$$ 5^2k^2 = 0  $$

i.e
$$ k = 0 \mod 2 $$

let $ 2j=k $
i.e.
$$ 10^n.x_n $$
$$ =16j^2-4j-10l $$ or
$$ =16j^2+4j-10l $$ or
$$ =100j^2-20j-10l $$ or
$$ =100j^2+20j-10l, 0<=l<n $$

And for anyone looking on, the $j$, $l$ and which "or" formulae can (will) vary for each $n$.

Comment: Note, you can conclude that $ y = 10k \pm 1$ quite easily. (I'm not certain why you used $2k\pm 1 $ and $5k\pm 1$ and the numerous other cases.) You can continue with this process, like $y = 100k \pm 1$ or $y = 100 \pm 49$, using the "Lifting the Exponent" Lemma.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Yep, as pointed out in the comments, my proof is wrong. I totally expected something like this. The fatal problem is that I missed some counterexamples in the general case.

I'm leaving this answer up, because as a rule I don't delete posts just for stuff like this, but that's what you get for trying to dive in head-first, I guess.
**/edit**

---

I know this is an old question, but I figured this would be a good exercise. First post on MSE, yadda yadda yadda. Hopefully the proof checks out.

I claim that there are no odd integers $x > 1$ such that the decimal representation of $x^2$ contains only the digits 0 and 1.

Suppose $x^2\equiv 1 \mod 10$. Then
$$x \equiv \pm1 \mod 10$$
Now we have $$x^2\equiv 1\vee x^2\equiv 11 \mod 100$$
($81=9^2$ is not counted since we are only allowed to use the digits 0 and 1).

But $11$ is not a perfect square. So that leaves only
$$x^2 \equiv 1 \mod 100.$$

In general, we can suppose we have proven that
$$x^2\equiv 1 \mod 10^k$$
It follows from this that
$$x\equiv \pm 1 \mod 10^k$$
Now notice that
$$x^2\equiv 1 \vee x^2\equiv 10^{k}+1 \mod 10^{k+1}$$
since by incrementing $k$, we are essentially adding another digit to the left of the number. By our rule, this extra digit can only be 0 or 1.

Now we need to show that $\sqrt{10^k+1}$ is irrational (see below). Then we are left with $$x^2\equiv 1 \mod 10^{k+1}.$$

By induction, therefore, $x^2\equiv1 \mod 10^k$ for all $k \ge 1$. Thus, the trivial $x^2=1$ is the only solution.

---

Now for my argument that $\sqrt{10^k+1}$ is irrational for all $k$:

Suppose $k\ge 0$ is even; then $10^k$ is a perfect square; thus $10^k+1$ is not a perfect square.

The case for odd $k$ can be verified numerically: we simply note that $\sqrt{10^k+1}-\sqrt{10^k}$ converges to zero for large $k$, and that $\sqrt{10^k}$ is irrational for odd $k$.

Comment: The problem is that just because $10^k+1$ isn't the square of an _integer_ doesn't mean that it's not a square $\mod 10^{k+1}$. Indeed, OP's original post shows that $1001$, while not a square, _is_ a square $\mod 10^4$ (it's the square of $4251$).

Comment: It's not true that if $x^2\equiv 1$ then $x\equiv\pm 1$. Take for example $x=51$ and look modulo $10^2$.

Comment: @Wojowu Yeah, I realized that now. On closer inspection though, I've realized the $\pm 1$ step wasn't really needed since we don't really care about $x$ anyway, only $x^2$. But Steven's objection is much more serious and pretty much kills the proof as it stands.